# Division by subtraction

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

Question:

> Divide A into B , assume A < B. The answer will be A goes into B q
>   times with a remainder of R
>
> Example: 7 goes into 20 2 times remainder 6
>
> Hint: Subtract A from B until A>the difference. Count how many times
>   you subtracted and the difference should be the remainder.
>
> ```
> Ex  20-7 = 13 
>     13 – 7 = 6
>     6 <7 so the count is 2 and the remainder is 6
> ```

This is my code. It's not complete. I don't know how to do this problem. Any help would be grateful.

```
TITLE       PROJECT
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
prompt1 byte 'Enter number A:',0
prompt2 byte 'Enter number B:',0
a dword ?
b dword ?
remainder dword ?
.code
main proc
    call clrscr

    mov eax,0
    mov ebx,0
    mov edx,offset prompt1
    call writestring
    call readint
    mov a,eax

    mov edx,offset prompt2
    call writestring
    call readint
    mov b,ebx

    mov eax,a
    mov ebx,b
    sub ebx,a       ;set edx to 0
    div ebx
    mov remainder,ebx
    ;xor eax,eax


    call writedec
    call crlf

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: So where is your loop? What is your problem?

Comment: sorry for late response. I don't know how to count remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop is implemented like this:

loop down:

```
    mov   ecx, 10   ; count from 10 to 0

 label:
    dec   ecx
    loop label
```

loop up:

```
   xor  ecx,ecx   ; count from 0 to 10
 label:
   inc ecx
   cmp ecx, 10
   jne label
```

Now think how your algorithm works and how to apply this information.

Comment: mov eax,a
      mov ebx,b
      sub ebx,a                                                                 xor  ecx,ecx   ; count from 0 to 10
 label:
   inc ecx
   cmp ecx, 10
   jne label       Can i just put your code under my code to make it go through a loop.

Comment: sorry i don't know how to write code in comment..

Comment: Do you have some knowledge in other languages like `C`? If yes, then you may want to write your algorithm first in C and keep it simple. Try to limit yourself to use only a small amount of variable, because the CPU doesn't have so many registers. This should help you to get an idea how the assembly should look like.